# How to integrate a function over a region?

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics, regions

In order to obtain a failure probability of an event, I need to integrate the `PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, 0], {x, y}]` over a region. In my case this region is defined by the following limit state function: `gx[x_, y_] := (((y + 4)/2)^2 + ((x + 4)/3)^2 - 2)`.

```
gx[x_, y_] := (((y + 4)/2)^2 + ((x + 4)/3)^2 - 2)
cplot = ContourPlot[{PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, 0], {x, y}]}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> 10];
rgplot= RegionPlot[gx[x, y] < 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}];
Show[cplot , rgplot]
```

[image]

How to compute this integral? I've tried this:

```
NIntegrate[
 PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0], {x, y}], {x, -4, 
  2/3 (-6 + Sqrt[2 - 8 x - x^2])}, {y, -4, 
  1/2 (-8 + 3 Sqrt[-8 - 8 y - y^2])}]
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[gx[x, y] < 0, {{x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}}];
NIntegrate[
 PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0], {x, y}],
 Element[{x, y}, reg]
 ]
```

> `0.0100282`

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this:

```
NProbability[gx[x, y] < 0 && -4 < x < 4 && -4 < y < 4, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
    BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, 0]]

(* Out: 0.0100282 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
pdf = PDF[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, 0], {x, y}];
gx[x_, y_] := (((y + 4)/2)^2 + ((x + 4)/3)^2 - 2)
```

(there's `{2,1`} in the question, but `{1,1}` was employed in the other two answers)

either

```
NIntegrate[pdf Boole[gx[x, y] < 0], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

> 0.0209579

or

```
NIntegrate[pdf Boole[gx[x, y] < 0], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]
```

> 0.0234098

depending on the need.